# VBA code to insert value in Excel based on values in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert program names into "F Column" according to the "switchtime" provided in the previous column. The "switch time" is compared with the master sheet(sheet1) to see what program was running when the switch happened.
These are the two sheets used.

[image]

[image]

But when running I get error message saying "SELECT Method of Range Class Failed".

```
Sub Protest()
    Dim chno, swtime, stime, ftime As Integer, swprog As String
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("F1").Select

    Do Until Selection.Offset(0, -3).Value = ""
        chno = Selection.Offset(0, -3).Value
        swtime = Selection.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If chno = "1" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4").Select
            Do Until Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value = ""
                stime = Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value
                ftime = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value
                If swtime >= stime And swtime <= ftime Then
                    swprog = Selection.Offset(0, -1).Value
                End If
                Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Loop
        End If

        If chno = "2" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I4").Select
            Do Until Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value = ""
                stime = Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value
                ftime = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value

                If swtime >= stime And swtime <= ftime Then

                    swprog = Selection.Offset(0, -1).Value
                End If


                Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Loop

        End If

        If chno = "3" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M4").Select
            Do Until Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value = ""
                stime = Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value
                ftime = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value

                If swtime >= stime And swtime <= ftime Then

                    swprog = Selection.Offset(0, -1).Value
                End If


                Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Loop

        End If

        Selection.Value = swprog
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You sure you want to use VBA? It can be done through formula too. Anyway, my guess is that when selecting cells your current active sheet is the wrong one. Most likely this line will get highlighted by VBA: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4").Select` Therefor it's best to avoid select completely and work through worksheet objects.

Comment: Can you share how to do it using formula?